# typescript widen to undefined union

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I am using Immutable.js with Typescript; I enabled the `--strict` option when compiling TypeScript and I am now getting an interesting error.

I have the following code:

```
import { Map } from "immutable";
class MyClass {
    public readonly map: Map<string, MyTypeA>

    public removeFromMap(keys: Seq.Indexed<string>): MyClass {
        const newMap = keys.reduce((r: Map<string, MyTypeA>, v: string, k: number) => {
            return r.remove(v);
        }, this.map);
        ...
    }
}
```

> Argument of type '(r: Map, v: string, k: number) => Map' is not assignable to parameter of type '(reduction?: Map | undefined, value?: string | undefined, key?: number | undefined, iter?: Iterable | undefined) => Map'.
>     Types of parameters 'r' and 'reduction' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Map | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Map'.
>         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Map'.

I can resolve this error by changing my code to

```
import { Map } from "immutable";
class MyClass {
    public readonly map: Map<string, MyTypeA>

    public removeFromMap(keys: Seq.Indexed<string>): MyClass {
        const newMap = keys.reduce((r: Map<string, MyTypeA> | undefined, v: string | undefined, k: number | undefined) => {
            return r!.remove(v!);
        }, this.map);
        ...
    }
}
```

but this is incredibly verbose. Why can TypeScript on strict mode not recognize in this case that type `string` is also of type `string | undefined`? I believe that this type widening happens in other areas of my codebase, but for some reason it's not happening here.

Is there a way to resolve this error in `--strict` mode in a less verbose way?

Comment: Aren't the types of the arguments to the callback you pass to `reduce` infered? I would not specify them at all

Comment: They are inferred, I didn't know that; so I can remove all type annotations entirely and pass `keys.reduce(r, v, _)`. It makes the code a little less clear though; would this be considered idiomatic and intuitive for "functional typescript"?

Comment: I have seen people around here specify all types everywhere, but its not the norm. Personally I am of the persuasion let the compiler infer all it can 

Comment: Also you don't need to have all parameters, you can remove the last ones if they are unused, a function with fewer parameters is still compatible with the callback

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that this type widening happens in other areas of my codebase, but for some reason it's not happening here.

## When it happens

When its safe e.g.

```
declare var str: string;
declare var strOrUndef: string | undefined;

strOrUndef = str; // OKAY
```

## When it doesn't happen

When its not safe! Your code simplified:

```
function iTakeFunctionThatIWillCallWithUndefined(
    fun: (hehe: string | undefined) => void
){
    fun(undefined);
}

iTakeFunctionThatIWillCallWithUndefined(function(str: string){ // Error
    // I expect it to be a string
})
```